# how to perform multiple buttons event handling onclick in listview

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have three buttons in listview. I need to perform multiple button click to trigger same method `checkInstall`. I dont know how to do. I have added relevant code:

**html file:**

```
 <ListView [items]="allAppsList" class="list-group">

   ....... 
   .......
   <StackLayout row="0" col="2">

      <Button  text= "Install" (tap) ="checkInstall($event, myIndex)" > </Button>   
      <Button text= "Open" (tap) ="checkInstall($event1, myIndex)" > </Button>   
      <Button text= "Remove"(tap) ="checkInstall($event2, myIndex)" > </Button>   

  </StackLayout>
 </ListView>
```

**ts file:**

```
checkInstall(args: EventData, index : number) : void {

}
```

for performing first button, checkInstall method working fine.But I dont know how to get the button id for second and third button to trigger separately for checkinstall to handle functionalities like hide and show the buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$event` is an angular key word, it has the output emitted value, you can not change it

```
<Button  text="Install" (tap)="checkInstall($event,1,  myIndex)"> </Button>   
<Button text="Open" (tap)="checkInstall($event, 2, myIndex)" > </Button>   
<Button text="Remove"(tap)="checkInstall($event, 3, myIndex)" > </Button>
```

You can send a parameter to your method

```
checkInstall(args: EventData, buttonIndex: number, index : number) : void {

}
```